# Geometrical explanation of the Cross Product

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Teaching myself multivariable calculus before class starts in August and got stuck with the following two questions which I have no one but you to ask. So any deep explanation would be great!

Show that if $u$, $v$, and $w$ are nonzero vectors and $(u \times v) \times w = 0$, then either: (i) $u$ and $v$ are parallel, or (ii) $w$ is orthogonal to $u$ and $v$.

Using the above solution, show that $u,v, w$ are nonzero and $(u \times v) \times w = u \times (v \times w) = 0$. Show that $u,v$, and $w$ are either mutually parallel or mutually perpendicular.

Comment: Please tell us how far you've gotten. When is the cross product of two vectors $\vec 0$? Also, in the second question, your first "show" is wrong. Try to apply the first question to do the second.

Comment: I think you mean (i) $u, v$ are collinear.

Comment: Isn't there a better tag for this?  This is purely a question of 3d vector algebra; it has nothing to do with vector calculus.

Comment: @Muphrid That may have been the context of the class where the algebra was taught.

Comment: Yeah, I did not mean to criticize the OP in any way; I'm just wondering if there really is a better tag already in use for a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

The cross-product of two vectors is a 3D vector orthogonal to the two. If the two vectors are not themselves in different directions, there is a whole plane orthogonal to the line spanned by the vector (both span the same one). So, the cross-product is the 0-vector. Conversely, if a cross-product of a vector with $w$ is 0, that vector lies on the same line as $w$. If that vector is not itself 0, it must mean $u, v$ are orthogonal to $w$. If that vector is in fact 0, $u, v$ must sit on the same line.